# By Python. making standard deviation and mean lines with different graphes

Tags: python, standards, deviation

Maybe the title seems bit confusing.

For example, there are three functions such as sin(x), 3 sine(x) and sin(x)+1. X would be from 1 to 100. How can I draw lines of mean with standard deviation (+ and -) for these three function values. I think that maybe I should calculate mean and standard deviation of three function values (sin(x), 3 sin(x) and sin(x)+1) at each x. However, I am not sure how I can do it with python. I know there are some function of standard deviation and mean in Scipy. Is that applicable for this case?
Maybe this is stupid question. However, I am pretty novice. I really appreciate any help.

Best regards,

Isaac

Comment: Do you mean how do you calculate confidence intervals? I'm assuming that you're not trying to "draw" the graphs on the screen?

Comment: I mean, the distribution of any function given a constant parameter is a degenerate distribution with a variance (hence standard deviation) of 0. So this is not what you want.

Comment: @Joel, I think he wants the moments, integrated or summed over the interval. E.g., for the stddev, `\int_1^100 (x * sin(x))`, or `\sum_1^100 (x * sin(x)) / n`. Isaac, does this looks like what you want?

Comment: @Evert: Oh I see. That makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you for Joel and Evert. I apologize for late answer. Actually I want to make one graph with standard deviation mean from several different graphes. As Evert said, integration or summation would be better description. Do you think that I should sum those functions up and devided by the number of functions?

Comment: @Isaac, it now sounds like you want to calculate the mean and stddev for every point separately, from the function values. I first thought you wanted something like average power (= the rms of a voltage sine wave).

Comment: @Isaac, I've now extended my answer to include a few other possibilities, though it's still not clear what your goal/question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but perhaps the following is a useful example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(1,100)
>>> m = (sin(x)+1).mean()
>>> s = (sin(x)+1).std()
>>> print m, s
1.00383024876 0.710743876537
```

*[edit after some further clarification]*

If, however, you want the average per x-point of the various functions, something like this would work:

```
>>> y = np.array([sin(x), 3*sin(x), sin(x)+1])
>>> m = y.mean(axis=0)
>>> s = y.std(axis=0)
```

which would give you 100 means and 100 stddevs.

If you want the average of the combined function, you're essentially back to the first example:

```
>>> m = (sin(x) + 3*sin(x) + sin(x)+1).mean()
>>> s = (sin(x) + 3*sin(x) + sin(x)+1).std()
>>> print m, s
1.01915124381 3.55371938269
```

Which option is the one applicable for you depends on the context of your question; I have no clue about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def function_1(X):
    return np.sin(X) 

def function_2(X):
    return 3. * np.sin(X) 

def function_3(X):
    return np.sin(X + 1.) 

X = np.arange(100)

# mean
print function_1(X).mean()

# std dev
print function_1(X).std()

# to plot
from matplotlib import pyplot as mp
mp.plot(X, function_1(X))
mp.hlines(function_1(X).mean(), 0, 100)
mp.show()
```

and so on... But do you really need to plot the "mean" of a sine function? Think about it ...

Comment: Thank you danodonovan. If I understand correctly,your code seems only plot the standard deviation and mean of function_1(x). Am I right? What I want to do is combining those three function into one graph with standard deviation and mean. Actually, What I really want to do is combining more than hundred spectra to one graph with mean and standard deviation. I just want to get idea. Thank you again.

Comment: How are you combining the functions? You could multiply, add, "convolve" - you can do all this with `function_*` ie `mean = function_1(x) + function_2(x) + function_3(x)` etc.

Comment: Thank you danodonovan, I should think more. Isaac